# Gettinga a syntax error on twilio

Tags: python, python-3.x, twilio, messaging

I am trying to send an sms to phone using python but when I run the script I am getting an invalid syntax error with highlight on twilio.rest ... 
Help would be appreciated..

```
import way2sms
import requests

q=way2sms.sms('Arjun','*****')
q.send('94184*****','Hlo')
n=q.msgSentToday()
q.logout()
```

Comment: Firstly, don't post links to images; post the code as text in the question. Secondly, yes you have several syntax issues in that code, which is why you get a syntax error.

Comment: change the first word `From` to `from`. Case matters.

Comment: Please read [ask], provide code *and errors* as text, not images. Also: what is `<'...'>` supposed to be? Remove `<` and `>` for str.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

There are a couple things that might be wrong with your code.

First up, as TheDarkKnight suggests in the comments, the first word `From` should be `from`.

You shouldn't include spaces in the phone numbers you are using.

Then, if you have just installed [the Twilio Python library](https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/python), then your code is likely to be out of date too as the way to import the REST client has changed. The updated code should look a bit like this:

```
from twilio.rest import Client

accountSid = "your_account_sid"
authToken  = "your_auth_token"

client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)

myTwilioNumber = "+91###"
destCellPhone  = "+91###"

myMessage = client.messages.create(
    body="whatever",
    to=destCellPhone, 
    from_=myTwilioNumber)
```

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: Made the changes and getting a big error     49mUnable to create record: The From phone number +919459261680 is not a valid, SMS-capable inbound phone number or short code for your account.[0m

[37m[49mMore information may be available here:[0m

[34m[49mhttps://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/21606[0m

Comment: Looks like the number you are trying to send from is not a Twilio number, it is a verified number in your account. You need to buy a Twilio number in the [phone numbers section of your console](https://www.twilio.com/console/phone-numbers/incoming) and use that as the from number.